# SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd1'

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, encoding, character-encoding

I wrote the following code

```
conAcc = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:\ThirdTask\Northwind.accdb')
SqlAccess=conAcc.cursor();
SqlAccess.execute(sql.sql_count_record_clients);
CountOfRecords=SqlAccess.fetchone();
conAcc.close();
```

where there is a line in module sql.py

```
sql_count_records_clients='''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Список клиентов"'''
```

As a result this line in sql.py gives out an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ThirdTask\connect.py", line 5, in <module>
    import json,sqlite3,sql
  File "D:\ThirdTask\sql.py", line 48
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd1' in file D:\ThirdTask\sql.py on line 48, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

What should be done to make the error disappear?

Comment: You're error message says it all: have you read [PEP263](http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html)?

Comment: may be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078851/syntaxerror-of-non-ascii-character

Answer (score 4):

Need add in first line code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
enter code here
```

Then problem resolve