# SyntaxError of Non-ASCII character

Tags: python, encoding, xml-parsing, lxml, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to parse xml which contains the some non ASCII cheracter,

the code looks like below

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml import objectify
content = u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><div>Order date                            : 05/08/2013 12:24:28</div>'
mail.replace('\xa0',' ')
xml = etree.fromstring(mail)
```

but it shows me error on the line 'content = ...'
like

```
syntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /home/projects/ztest/responce.py on line 3, 
but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

in the terminal it's working but while running on the eclipse IDE it's giving me a error.

Don't know how to overcome..

Comment: I don't think it a duplicate. People encounter this python encoding issue very often. Having this rich style of problem descriptions in SO makes our knowledge base better.

Comment: YOU WILL LIKELY GET THIS ERROR if you import a PYTHON 3 file into the PYTHON 2 interpreter. *(This question should not be closed - '\xc2' is a very particular sort of problem - and very different to that raised by the supposed duplicate question. The answer should be made clear here).*

Answer (score 282, accepted):

You should define source code encoding, add this to the top of your script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

The reason why it works differently in console and in the IDE is, likely, because of different default encodings set. You can check it by running:

```
import sys
print sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

Also see:

- [Why declare unicode by string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170211/why-declare-unicode-by-string-in-python)
- [Changing default encoding of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python)
- [Correct way to define Python source code encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728891/correct-way-to-define-python-source-code-encoding)

Comment: If I do not include this line then python3 does not throw the error. However, python2 does. The only way to make it work with python2 is to add this line `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`. but why?