# Python printing special Characters

Tags: python, character

In Python how do I print special characters such as √, ∞, ²,³, ≤, ≥, ±, ≠

When I try printing this to the console I the get this error:

```
print("√")

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /Users/williamfiset/Desktop/MathAid - Python/test.py on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: It doesn't answer my question sorry

Comment: Put `# code: utf-8` at the very first line of the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running this code results into the same `SyntaxError` you've provided:

```
chars = ["√", "∞", "²","³", "≤", "≥", "±", "≠"]
for c in chars:
    print(c)
```

But if I add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

chars = ["√", "∞", "²","³", "≤", "≥", "±", "≠"]
for c in chars:
    print(c)
```

it will print:

```
√
∞
²
³
≤
≥
±
≠
```

Also, see [SyntaxError of Non-ASCII character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078851/syntaxerror-of-non-ascii-character).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you, the answer is very clear