# Python non-ascii error for hashtag

Tags: python, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to call a C executable from Python script. Obviously, my C code has '#include's at start and that's what's giving me error when I call the C executable from Python. I use subprocess.call to call the executable as follows:

```
>>> subprocess.call([sys.executable,"motor_control","50","1","50","1"])
```

And I get the following error:

```
File "motor_control", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xdd' in file motor_control on line
2, but no encoding declared; see
http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details 1
```

Line 1, Line 2 etc all have '#include's. Motor_control is the executable, which has numeric arguments 50, 1, 50, 1. I ran motor_control from terminal and it runs fine. I googled a lot but most similar errors are for other non-ascii characters and I did not find any answer related to '\xdd', which is the hashtag at '#include'. Which means nobody is getting error at #include's, which means I'm missing something really basic. But I'm not sure what.

Some other answers here, for example:
[SyntaxError of Non-ASCII character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078851/syntaxerror-of-non-ascii-character)
mention adding

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

to the start of the python script, however that did not work for me. Adding

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

also did not work, as was mentioned by someone else.

I'm running this code on PCduino (C code is executed in c_environment for pcduino (help for this is [here](http://www.pcduino.com/chapter-3-c-language-and-arduino-type-ide-for-pcduino/))). Python and C independently works fine on this hardware.
Is there something I need to do differently for calling C code having #?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
subprocess.call([sys.executable,"motor_control","50","1","50","1"])
```

The  above command will translate to `/usr/bin/python motor_control 50 1 50 1`  and be executed

so what your doing is that passing the excutable to python interpreter which is wrong

Try This:

```
subprocess.call(["/pathtoexecutable/motor_control","50","1","50","1"])
```

Comment: I already tried
subprocess.call(["/pathtoexecutable/motor_control","50","1","50","1"]) 

It says OSError 13: Permission denied. now the path to motor_control is /home/ubuntu/c_environment/output/test/motor_control. I made sure to chmod motor_control to make it executable. I dont think this folder has any restrictions as well. 
I used the sys.executable command just because it did not give permission error, but I see what you mean, and I wont try that again.
But is there any particular reason why I'm getting permission error?

Comment: can you provide the file permissions of your file? you can use the python command `oct(stat.S_IMODE(os.stat("motor_control").st_mode))`, to make it work , you have to import os,stat include the above command in you python script and try printing the file permissions